# Can we always find a prime of the form $\ p$#$+q\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

> Conjecture : If $\ q\ $ is an odd prime, there is always a prime $\ p<q\ $ such that $\ p$#$+q\ $ is prime.

$p$# $= 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots p\ $ is the primorial

This conjecture holds upto at least $\ 2\cdot 10^6\ $.

If we go upto $\ p=3200\ $ , the following $\ 41\ $ primes $\ q\le 10^8\ $ remain unsolved

```
[2173663, 9069217, 12759883, 15507827, 19582841, 19910833, 22686179, 25852909, 2
6277593, 28131179, 31054651, 34916879, 37117099, 38415271, 39765263, 40138019, 4
1140279, 43881083, 48265883, 52680623, 53129933, 57269941, 58942783, 59830109, 6
1308073, 61390057, 61392613, 61533467, 64493843, 68988053, 71345369, 73913599, 7
7045201, 79594259, 80342609, 82071553, 83446267, 85440581, 86935411, 93010331, 9
4369643]
```

For a large prime $q$, heuristically there should be a prime of the form $\ p$#$+q\ $ because such a number has no prime factor upto $p$, so the chance should be good that it is prime. Is there any hope to prove this conjecture ?

Update : The number $\ 45979$#$+25852909\ $ is probable prime.

Comment: You undoubtedly are aware of this, but for anybody reading this who isn't, this is quite closely related to the [Fortunate number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunate_number), i.e., "the smallest integer $m \gt 1$ such that, for a given positive integer $n$, $p_n\# + m$ is a prime number". The Wikipedia article also states "Reo Fortune conjectured that no Fortunate number is composite (*Fortune's conjecture*). A **Fortunate prime** is a Fortunate number which is also a prime number. As of 2012, all the known Fortunate numbers are prime."

Comment: The same question has been asked last week. The probability that $p\#+q$ is prime is around $\frac{\log \log p\#+q}{\log p\#+q} \approx C_q \frac{\log p}{p}$. To find if (under the random model) the conjecture has a chance to hold we need to determinate $C_q$

Comment: @reuns Please provide a link to that question, even if it's since been deleted, which was asked last week. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnOmielan No, I was not aware of the "fortunate numbers". The smallest prime $q$ , for which I did not find a solution , is $q=25\ 852\ 909$ , for which $p$ must be greater than $25\ 000$

Comment: @Peter You seemed to be so knowledgeable about number theory with your numerous interesting & insightful related questions & answers that I assumed you likely knew about "fortunate numbers". For what it's worth, I agree with your last paragraph about the heuristic chances of your conjecture being true for large $q$ but, as with "fortunate numbers" & so many other number theory conjectures, I don't think there's much hope in proving them (although a counter-example may be found if there are wrong) until after some significant new prime behavior related discovery is made.

Comment: other than all all p#>6 being 6 or 18 mod 24 I got nothing.

Comment: An observation: Not every prime is a Fortunate number; e.g. $11$ is not. Although $p_3\#+11=41$ is prime, $p_3\#+7=37$ is prime, and $7<11$ so $7$ is the  Fortunate number associated with $p_3\#$. I introduce the notion of rank. Original Fortunate numbers are first rank Fortunate numbers: the smallest integer $m_1>1$ such that for a given $n,\ p_n\#+m_1$ is prime. A $k$th rank Fortunate number would be the smallest integer $m_k>m_{k-1}$ such that for a given $n,\ p_n\#+m_k$ is prime. Peter's conjecture would then  be that every prime $q$ is a Fortunate number of some rank.

Comment: When you write, "this conjecture holds up to at least $2\cdot10^6$," do you mean that you have found primes, or that you have found "probable primes"?

Comment: I do not remember exactly whether I worked with rigorous primes in this range, but I think the primes in this range are proven.

Comment: Considering the magnitude of $3200$#, primality proving is still well feasible in pari/gp, so I think this is actually the meaning of "at least $2\cdot 10^6$"

Comment: In a doublecheck , I approved that the cases upto $10^8$ where some $p<100$ does the job leads to a proven prime with the minimum $p$. If we can trust the BPSW-test for such numbers, all cases upto $10^8$ besides $15$ that give larger probable primes are solved, and all of those $15$ either pass $20$ miller rabin bases or (in the updated case) , it is sprp to the prime bases in the range $40-110$

Comment: So, we can safely assume that the conjecture is true upto $10^8$ , but purists won't be satisfied since not all the primes have been proven to be prime.