# Another question about numbers of the form $p_i\#+p_{n+1}$

Tags: twin-primes, primorial

This is a follow on question to the question posted by Peter ([Can we always find a prime of the form $\ p$#$+q\ $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306020/can-we-always-find-a-prime-of-the-form-pq)). Replacing his variable $q$ with $p_{n+1}$, his conjecture in that question can be formulated as:

For all $n$, and $1\le i\le n$, the set $\{p_i\#+p_{n+1}\}$ contains at least one prime number.

I have been playing around with numbers, calculating primorials, etc., to see if I could observe any patterns that might shed light on the question. So far, no insights.

What I have noticed is that for $n=1,2$, every member of the set $\{p_i\#+p_{n+1}\}$ is a prime, but for $n>2$ there are always some composite numbers in the set. I have only been able to look up to $n=13$. In some instances ($n=6,\ 12$) a large fraction of the elements in a set are prime.

**My question is**: Is there any $n>2$ for which the set $\{p_i\#+p_{n+1}\}$ (where ($1\le i\le n$)) contains only prime numbers?

Some comments: $p_{n+1}$ must be the smaller member of a pair of twin primes, and the smaller member of a pair of sexy primes, since $p_1\#+p_{n+1}$ and $p_2\#+p_{n+1}$ must be a prime ($p_1\#=2$ and $p_2\#=6$). So if the twin prime conjecture were false, there would be some $n_0$ above which there could be no examples of that set containing all primes. Also, the larger $n$ becomes, the more sums are required to be prime, in ranges of numbers where primes become less frequent, which makes me feel that sets containing all primes will become less probable as $n$ becomes very large. Nonetheless, I cannot discover a line of reasoning that says such sets are impossible. Perhaps someone with access to greater computing power can find an example of such a set, or someone with deeper insights into number theory may see a way to prove such sets are either necessary or impossible.

Comment: If you did not find an example for a moderate $n$, lets say $n\le 20$ , it is extremely unlikely that such $n$ exists. The "danger" that the twin prime conjecture is false is very small, although we cannot yet rule it out. I also see at the moment no disproof, on the other hand. We can however verify the conjecture upto a very high level because ONE composite is enough to rule out a specific prime. How far did you check the conjecture ?

Comment: According to my search , a composite appears for every prime $p$ with $7\le p\le 10^9$. It is almost impossible that we can have only primes for $p>5$

Comment: Upto $4\cdot 10^9$ , the only prime, for which a composite appears as late as for the prime $41$ , is $729457511$. In particular, for $4\cdot 10^9$ , such an $n$ does not exist. This convinces me that there is no such $n$, although I have no proof.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for using your computational abilities to affirm what I also suspected. No proof, but virtually no chance that such an $n$ exists.